# AngularJS is not sending Auth header

Tags: angularjs, header

im trying to make an interceptor that appends an user token if exists on every request, the token exists but it doesnt send it... After the call is made I look at F12 ( Chrome Dev Tools) the call and the Authorization header is not there...

But if I debug it step by step I can see how in the config.headers.Authorization is there my token... but still not sending it throu the request... May I ask for some help please?

This is my interceptor

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location, $cookies){
    return {
        request: function(config){
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            let token = $cookies.get('user');
            if (token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response){
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function(response){
            if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403){
                $location.path('/login')
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
  })
```

CORS config

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization');
    next();
}
```

Config before it be send

[image: config before it be send]

req/res preflight
[image: req/res preflight]

Comment: Does your preflight `options` request return `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization`?

Comment: Yes It does, those are the allowed headers I've put on my server side

Comment: Could you try to `console.log(config);` directly above `return config;` is your configuration inside? It all seems fine to me right now.

Comment: Okay, I've just attached the picture to the OP, it seems all right to me too, im attaching the req/res on the preflight too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your `OPTIONS` request does not need an "auth" and you will be fine. The [W3 spec for **CORS preflight requests**](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#preflight-request) says that user credentials should be excluded.

If HTTP-Status `401` has been returned by an `OPTIONS` request , a subrequest should not be send by the client. But it seems like there is a bug with some browsers. This browsers does send a subrequest even if the `OPTIONS` request returned `401`.

In `node.js` you could check the request method by using `req.method === 'OPTIONS'`.

Comment: Thanks you, this fixed my problem, i've justs added this
        if (req.method === "OPTIONS") 
            res.sendStatus(200);
        else 
            next();